# Why my ListView in SwipeRefreshLayout don't show the last element on Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

I have a `ViewPager` with Tabs and on inside on it a `Fragment` with `SwipeRefreshLayout` and inside of it a `ListView` with some elements for testing.

I scroll down the list normally at the bottom and, I noticed that the last element is not showing correctly.
I search for the correct layout, but I still have the same problem.

How to fix?

[image]

Here is my code.

> ActivityMain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Fragment Job SwipeRefreshLayout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

> JobListRow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="15-1812"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="625 Gallatian/Sunrise"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        android:layout_below="@+id/job_id"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_brand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sunrise"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
        android:layout_below="@+id/job_description"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_status_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Active"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Might help if you have `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` set as an attribute under your `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected my problem implementing a **RecyclerView** instead of a **ListView**, adding scrollFlags to the **TabLayout** changing the layout for the **SwipeRefreshLayout** and **MainActivity**.

Here is the solution.

> ActivityMain

```
...
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
...
```

> Fragment_Job_SwipeRefreshLayout

```
...
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_jobs_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/jobsRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
...
```

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your sample you can use listview in Relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  ></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I implement your suggest for the layout and it causes a little bug with the **SwipeRefreshLayout** when I try to scroll down always active the Pull To Refresh action.

Comment: Pull To Refresh calls when list scrolling ends. I think you have to increase the elements in Listview(size of List).